# subtract 2 datetime in mysql ( one in 24 hours format and one in am/pm format )

Tags: mysql, datetime

I'm trying to create a query using mysql.

```
select ID,NCOde,ifnull(EndTime,now())-starttime from xxx where starttime between 
'2012-05-09 00:00:00' and '2012-05-09 23:59:59'
```

the problem is ifnull(EndTime,now()) return datetime in 24 hours format, while the starttime using am/pm format.

I've tried using `DATE_FORMAT(starttime, '%m-%d-%Y %T')`, but it seems that the operation changed the datetime type to other type.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) to convert your `starttime` string to a MySQL `DATETIME`:

```
STR_TO_DATE(starttime, '%m-%d-%Y %r')
```

and then use [`TIMEDIFF()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff) to subtract two times:

```
select ID,NCOde,
  TIMEDIFF(ifnull(EndTime,now()), STR_TO_DATE(starttime, '%m-%d-%Y %r'))
from xxx
where STR_TO_DATE(starttime,'%m-%d-%Y %r')
        between '2012-05-09 00:00:00' and '2012-05-09 23:59:59'
```

You should probably consider changing the data type of the `starttime` column to [`DATETIME`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/datetime.html) or [`TIMESTAMP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/datetime.html).  Note also that this assumes `EndTime` is already of such a data type, or else you will also have to perform a similar conversion with it too.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to reply, I get distracted by another assignment. For my case, both the starttime and endtime are datetime, but one in 24 hour format, while the other in am/pm format. But the substraction gives wrong result. How do I change one format but still keep the type as datetime?

Comment: @wongchungyie: If the `starttime` and `endtime` columns are of the MySQL [`DATETIME`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/datetime.html) data type, then they must both "be" in 24hr format; for one to be in 12hr format, it must be some other data type - perhaps a string type like `VARCHAR`?  If that's the case, then you must provide the appropriate [formatting string](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) as the second argument to `STR_TO_DATE` in order for MySQL to parse the string to a `DATETIME` as shown above (e.g. for 24hr time, use `%T` instead of `%r`).

Answer (score 0):

Use the [DATE_SUB()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub) function.

Plus what eggyal said.