# why is mysql subtracting 10 hours in this str_to_date() call

Tags: mysql

mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.28, for osx10.14 (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

```
mysql> select str_to_date('2019-11-13 09:32:51', '%Y-%m-%D %H:%i:%s');
select str_to_date('2019-11-13 09:32:51', '%Y-%m-%D %H:%i:%s');
+---------------------------------------------------------+
| str_to_date('2019-11-13 09:32:51', '%Y-%m-%D %H:%i:%s') |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
| 2019-11-13 09:32:51                                     |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

All good there.   But then....

```
mysql> select str_to_date('2019-11-13 10:32:51', '%Y-%m-%D %H:%i:%s');
select str_to_date('2019-11-13 10:32:51', '%Y-%m-%D %H:%i:%s');
+---------------------------------------------------------+
| str_to_date('2019-11-13 10:32:51', '%Y-%m-%D %H:%i:%s') |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
| 2019-11-13 00:32:51                                     |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

When the hours in the string >= 10, the converted DATETIME is missing 10 hours.

[image]

Comment: d not D see manual for parameters for this function https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to P. Salmon comment, the correct formulation is:

```
select str_to_date('2019-11-13 10:32:51', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s');
+---------------------------------------------------------+
| str_to_date('2019-11-13 10:32:51', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
| 2019-11-13 10:32:51                                     |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score -1):

Use STR_TO_DATE() to convert your starttime string to a MySQL DATETIME:

```
STR_TO_DATE(starttime, '%m-%d-%Y %r')
```

and then use TIMEDIFF() to subtract two times:

```
select ID,NCOde,   TIMEDIFF(ifnull(EndTime,now()), STR_TO_DATE(starttime, '%m-%d-%Y %r')) 
from xxx where STR_TO_DATE(starttime,'%m-%d-%Y %r')
    between '2012-05-09 00:00:00' and '2012-05-09 23:59:59'
```

You should probably consider changing the data type of the starttime column to DATETIME or TIMESTAMP. Note also that this assumes EndTime is already of such a data type, or else you will also have to perform a similar conversion with it too.

If the starttime and endtime columns are of the MySQL DATETIME data type, then they must both "be" in 24hr format; for one to be in 12hr format, it must be some other data type - perhaps a string type like VARCHAR? If that's the case, then you must provide the appropriate formatting string as the second argument to STR_TO_DATE in order for MySQL to parse the string to a DATETIME as shown above (e.g. for 24hr time, use %T instead of %r)

**OR**

mySQL has DATE_SUB():

```
SELECT DATE_SUB(column, INTERVAL 3 HOUR)
```

Comment: not really an answer to the question.   Also seems to be a cut and paste of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10514685/subtract-2-datetime-in-mysql-one-in-24-hours-format-and-one-in-am-pm-format